# Why do we need two constructors in Room?

Tags: android, database, constructor, android-room

One with an id and the other one without. Also, why is not possible to delete a constructor? Why must @Ignore be specified instead? Thank you in advance.

I'm referring to Entity. Here's the code I'm referring to and the Url.

```
@Entity(primaryKeys={"id", "versionCode"})
class VersionedThingy {
  @NonNull public final String id;
  public final int versionCode;

  @Ignore
  private String something;

  VersionedThingy(String id, int versionCode) {
    this.id=id;
    this.versionCode=versionCode;
  }
}
```

https://commonsware.com/AndroidArch/previews/the-dao-of-entities

Comment: What do you mean, can you post your entity object ?

Comment: When you say `Room`, which class do you mean? The one annotated with `@Entity`, or `@Dao` or `@Database` ? But in all these cases you don't need two constructors, just one is sufficient.

Comment: there is only one constructor?? while ordinary one has to annotate them all with `@Ignore`, but one.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation here : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Entity, which said:

> Each entity must either have a no-arg constructor or a constructor whose parameters match fields (based on type and name). Constructor does not have to receive all fields as parameters but if a field is not passed into the constructor, it should either be public or have a public setter. If a matching constructor is available, Room will always use it. If you don't want it to use a constructor, you can annotate it with Ignore.
>
> When a class is marked as an Entity, all of its fields are persisted.
>   If you would like to exclude some of its fields, you can mark them
>   with Ignore.
>
> If a field is transient, it is automatically ignored unless it is
>   annotated with ColumnInfo, Embedded or Relation.

So, you can use only one constructor depends on that which fields you need in the `Database`

Hope I helped somehow :)

Comment: I understand that you can only use on constructor. But why can't the other constructor be deleted? Why do we have to put @Ignore above it?